# Single Page Application: Analytics Broken For Paid Traffic

Tags: tracking, bounce-rate, single-page-application

I am struggling with an issue and can't find a solution online, so I am hoping you can help us out here :-)

For our event location booking platform, which is iteratively upgraded to a ReactJS application. Currently the single page application should be involving two different page types: [filter pages](https://www.eventinc.de/eventlocation/hamburg) and [provider pages](https://www.eventinc.de/eventlocation/hamburg/kai-10-the-floating-experience) (links are examples). The usual user journey makes the user switch between filter and provider pages quite frequently, thus we would like to prevent new page loads whenever it happens.

We tried the history change event for not messing with our analytics.

First we had this passively configured into the tag manager for every URL change. This seemed to work out great for filter pages alone (for when the user uses filters). As soon as involved the provider pages into the SPA, this happened to our analytics though (active from 29th to 2nd):

[image: (Orange line = bounce rate for paid traffic / blue line = bounce rate for organic traffic)]

A similar pattern could also be seen for other metrics.

Since this is obviously a problem, we switched the react routing between both site types off again and implemented a different approach. This time we pushed the history change event instead of having it attached to the pageview event that we push on every page view. Sadly though, we encountered the same issue.

Now we are pretty lost about what might cause SEA traffic to not be tracked correctly anymore. Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong here?

PS: In case this is important: We are currently still running two GTM containers for legacy reasons - in this instance we only care about GTM-5GX5BDH.